# When we transfer from this page to another, the application will have a one-second delay

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, instruments

We have here a page which contains quite a few UITableView.

When we transfer from this page to another, the application will have a one-second delay.

And there is another one-second delay when we transfer from the other page to the first page mentioned above.

Instruments reveals that the LayoutSublayers Method takes most part of the very one second, as showed in the picture below:
[image]
Can anyone tell me how to optimize the performance and kill the delay? I will appreciate any good suggestions.

Comment: the test device is iPhone4